# Is there a way to see the GUI lively when stepping the code in OllyDbg?

Tags: debugging, reverse-engineering, ollydbg

I wanted to know if there is some way to view the GUI while stepping the code in OllyDbg so I can find out when a message appears. When I step the code the GUI is frozen and I won't notice when the message appears. I have also tried placing breakpoints on APIs and other things but that didn't help. Just wanted to know if there is some way or some plugin to let me view the GUI while stepping.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

It is not really possible to step through the creation of each of the UI elements. You could, however, break on certain UI events ( like MessageBox, Window creation etc ). 
In your case, you can conditionally break on, for instance, the MessageBox function or its variants when the message matches your needs. Ollydbg's conditional breakpoints should be of help to you.

Answer (score 0):

The GUI is freezed becuse you are stepping throught the code, when you debugg a program you control the program flux so if the program wants to show a messagebox it will do if you step in the instruction that makes it happen like ShowMessageBoxA or similar.

You have this question becuse you really don't understend how debugging works so, if you are following some reverse engeneering lessons first study a bit of debuggin, i suggest that you make some simple programs in C and try to reverse them after trying advanced lessons.

This site have a lot of good tutorials: [Here](https://tuts4you.com/download.php)

If you want to start reverse engeneering, get these tutorials from LENA:[Here](https://tuts4you.com/download.php?list.17)

Aways use virtual machine for reversing even for the totorials ;)